# Variadic generic function accepting generic types as input arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Suppose we have some concrete types `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. Also we have a wrapper type: `Wrapper<T>` where `T` could be any types e.g. `A`, `B`.

I need a variadic function that takes some `Wrapper<T>`s and returns the wrapped values as a tuple: `[]`.

```
let wa: Wrapper<A>;
let wb: Wrapper<B>;
let wc: Wrapper<C>;
let result = myFunction(wa, wb, wc);
```

In this example `result` should be of type `[A, B, C]`. I don't know how to write the type of `myFunction`. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a rough idea of how many wrapped arguments you want to pass to your functions, the simples option is to use a set of overloads. Something like this

```js
type Wrapper<T> = {
    type: T
}

type A = number
type B = boolean
type C = string

function f<A, B, C>(w1: Wrapper<A>, w2: Wrapper<B>, w3: Wrapper<C>): [A, B, C]
function f<A, B>(w1: Wrapper<A>, w2: Wrapper<B>): [A, B]
function f<A>(w1: Wrapper<A>): [A]
function f(...ws: Wrapper<any>[]): any[] {
    return ws.map(w => w.type)
}

declare const a: Wrapper<A>
declare const b: Wrapper<B>
declare const c: Wrapper<C>

const foo = f(a, b, c) // [A, B, C]
```

Answer (score 1):

this can be done with a tuple type

```
function foo<T extends any[]>(...args: T): T {
    return args;
}
// you dont need to pass generic parameters ofc. typescript will infer same type anyway
// return type of this function is now [string, number, object]
foo<[string, number, object]>("a", 1, {});
```

here is [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAhAhAeAKsgpgDxlwgBMBnZAQwgE8BtAXQD4AKAOg8oCcBzMgLmRYAlIJwBvYMmnIuuGGC4pufANzAAvsFDoMdMjC5wIPADTIIYALYAjXF3MIbAK1yxmLAESVP5gIzm4hrCqkA)

Comment: What if you want the arguments to be functions that provide a T? For example, something like ```function foo<T extends any[]>(...args: (bar: Bar) => T): T { return args; }```
Is this possible?

Comment: To clarify, I would then want the return type of `foo((bar: Bar) => string, (bar: Bar) => number)` to be `[string, number]` (and not `[(bar: Bar) => string, (bar: Bar) => number)]`)